# Como borrar datos un array

Tags: java, netbeans, pop

Como puedo hacer para que únicamente se borre el ultimo dato del array.

**Código**

```
 String datos="2*3+4/2";  

 String[] almacenar = datos.split("");

 almacenar =almacenar.length-1;

 System.out.println(datos);
```

Comment: un array al ser de tamaño estatico, no puede modificarse la longitud con la que es declarado,si es de tamaño 3 siempre sera 3, entonces no se puede borrar ninguna posición, lo que puedes hacer es reemplazar ese ultimo dato por un valor diferente o crear un nuevo array con una longitud menor donde guardes los datos del primer array exceptuando los datos que queres "borrar"

Comment: mirate esta página https://www.techiedelight.com/es/remove-last-element-from-an-array-in-java/ creo que puede resultarte util

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabajar con arrays podrías importar la siguiente librería:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Y luego podrías hacer una copia del array y reemplazarlo por el mismo pero con la longitud -1 (o sea sin el último elemento del array) usando el método [**`copyOf()`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-copyof-in-java-with-examples/), sería algo como:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String datos = "2*3+4/2";
    String[] datosArr = datos.split(""); // divido al string en elementos de un array usando a "" como separador.
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datosArr)); // obtengo al string como array => [2, *, 3, +, 4, /, 2].
    
    datosArr = Arrays.copyOf(datosArr, datosArr.length - 1); // aquí copio al array y reemplazo por el mismo array pero con longitud -1 (osea obtengo el array sin el último elemento).
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(datosArr)); // y obtengo => [2, *, 3, +, 4, /]
  }
```

**Output:**

```
// [2, *, 3, +, 4, /, 2]
// [2, *, 3, +, 4, /]
```

Comment: Y si quiera transformar el array en un String como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @Rosa recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió, así tu pregunta estará como respondida. Ya está transformado el array en string con `...toString(datosArr)`